# How to solve error EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/db.json'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, json-server

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')

const server = jsonServer.create()
const router = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, 'db.json'))
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

server.use(cors())
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser)
server.use(middlewares)
server.use(router)

const PORT = 8000

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`JSON Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

I am using cyclic.sh for deployment. How to solve this error?

I was trying to deploy a json-server. And while doing a post request I got this error.

Comment: Perhaps cyclic.sh does not give you a writable file system?

Comment: can you suggest one where it is available? @HeikoTheißen

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Taking as a starting point that you shouldn't use a tool like json-server in production environments, I could understand you might be using it for **demo purposes**. That case, there are some serverless solutions which prevents your code from open files in write mode, so that's why the `jsonServer.router(...)` line fails its execution.

If you don't matter about that `db.json` file being updated by the requests (because anyway, your deployment solution doesn't seem to allow it), you could just use instead a js object, that can be modified in memory (but, of course, the json file will still keep intact). So, instead of:

```js
const router = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, 'db.json'))
```

try using something like:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'db.json')))
const router = jsonServer.router(db)
```